# Здравствуйте, можете пожалуйста помочь с решением и разъяснить почему моё решение не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```
let min = parseInt(prompt("Start range: ") < 100);

var numbers = []
for (var i = min; i <= 100; i++) {
    let rest = i % 5;

    if (rest === 2 || 3) {
        console.log('Shared with the remainder');
    } else {
        console.log("No any number")
    }
}
```

Мне нужно вывести все числа между X и Y, которые при делении на 5 дают остаток равный 2 или 3. Если таких чисел не нашлось, то вывести “No any number”. X у меня это переменная min, а максимум по условию 100, поэтому не прошу пользователя его задать

Можете **пожалуйста** помочь с решением и если не сложно, то объяснить его?

Comment: Неправильно мыслите про условие. `   if (rest == 2 || rest == 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Строка `let min = parseInt(prompt("Start range: ") < 100);` некорректная.
2. Строка `var numbers = []` - лишняя (переменная не используется)
3. Строку `console.log("No any number")` надо вынести за цикл и добавить признак положительного сравнения с остатками (например, `has_any`).
4. Для сравнения можно также использовать массив и `includes()` (или множество и `has()`). Это удобно, когда сравниваемых значений много.

```js
let min = Math.min(parseInt(prompt("Start range: "), 10), 99);
let has_any = false;
let remainders = [2, 3];

for (let i = min; i <= 100; i++) {
    let rest = i % 5;
    if (remainders.includes(rest)) {
        console.log(`${i} Shared with the remainder ${remainders}`);
        has_any = true;
    }
}
if (!has_any) console.log("No any number")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь и объяснение!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
rest === 2 || 3
```

Это невалидная конструкция. В программировании (во всяком случае в JS) такое не работает. Правильно писать

```
rest === 2 || rest === 3
```

т.е. каждое условие писать отдельно, разделяя знаком логического условия